# how to understand this sentence in mysql: each NULL column takes one bit extra

Tags: mysql, null, myisam

in the mysql manual:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html there are a example in above link,the example code paste below.

the manual say that each NULL column takes one bit,rounded up to the nearest byte.

i do not understand, as for below example, i think that 2 null columns take 2 bit and round to 1 byte. 32765 + 32766 + 1 = 65532, but in fact mysql occurs error that the row size exceed the 65535, what is wrong with my thought? please point out!

```
CREATE TABLE t3
(c1 VARCHAR(32765) NULL, c2 VARCHAR(32766) NULL)
ENGINE = MyISAM CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

result:

> ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used 
>   table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, 
>   check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

hope someone can explain it specifically in simple syntax, i am not good at English, thank you very much!

Comment: The key statement here in the docs is _This includes storage overhead_.  Clearly you are exceeding 65K or it would allow your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

For (latin1) VARCHAR(L), the required storage is "L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 − 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes".

So your columns take 2 extra bytes each for the length, plus one extra byte for the null flags for the table.  That's 32765+2+32766+2+1=65536

Answer (score 1):

Since no "column value" corresponds to `NULL`, MySQL uses an extra flag to indicate that the column is `NULL`.  (In which case any data that might be in the "column value" area are ignored because "they're not there.")

Seriously, if you are running into the row-size limit, you probably need to re-think the design of your table(s).  (Are there "repeating groups?"  Column-names like `name_23, name_24 ...`?)  The data could be divided into more than one table.  And, so on.  The architectural limits should be "plenty big enough."